# firebase on('value') with await does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to build function to wait until all values in on('value') will be set and then go to the next line, in other words async function.

```
 let upcomingGamesList = await firebase.database().ref('UpcomingGames').on('value', snapshot => {
        upcomingGamesList = snapshot.val()
        console.log('upcoming t1',upcomingGamesList)
        return upcomingGamesList
    })
    console.log('upcoming t2',upcomingGamesList)
    let upcomingPreferences = upcomingGamesList.map(async(game) => {
        console.log(game)
        let GameId = game.GameId
        await firebase.database().ref(`GameNotificationPreferances/${GameId}`).orderByKey().equalTo(UserStore.user.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val() != null || snapshot.val() != undefined) {
                conosle.log(snapshot.val())
            } else {
                console.log('not value')
            }
        })
        console.log(game)
    })
```

what that happened is the upcoming t2

```
        console.log('upcoming t2',upcomingGamesList)
```

is printed before upcoming t1

```
    console.log('upcoming t2',upcomingGamesList)
```

But I used await in this function

```
  let upcomingGamesList = await firebase.database().ref('UpcomingGames').on('value', snapshot => {
        upcomingGamesList = snapshot.val()
        console.log('upcoming t2',upcomingGamesList)
        return upcomingGamesList
    })
```

and it should wait until it finish and then go to next line

I want to wait until the function will finish and then get the updatedList with the change i did

```
 let upcomingGamesList = await firebase.database().ref('UpcomingGames').on('value', async(snapshot) => {
        upcomingGamesList = snapshot.val()
        updatededList = await upcomingGamesList.map(async(game) => {
            let GameId = game.GameId
            await firebase.database().ref(`GameNotificationPreferances/${GameId}`).orderByKey().equalTo(UserStore.user.uid).once('value', async(snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.val() != null || snapshot.val() != undefined) {
                    game['reminderPressed'] = true;
                } else {
                    game['reminderPressed'] = false
                }
                console.log('GameId:',GameId, 'GameDetails:',game)
                return ({...game})

            })

        })


    })
    console.log('the updatedList is',updatededList)
```

Answer (score 12):

Firebase's `on()` function will continuously listen to the location that you call them on. That means that they can give you data multiple times. Since a `Promise` can only resolve once, `on()` does not return a promise. And thus it can't be used with `async`/`await`.

In this case it looks like you'll want to use `once()`, which works pretty much the same but will only deliver a result once (and thus returns a promise):

```
let upcomingGamesList = await firebase.database().ref('UpcomingGames').once('value', snapshot => {
    upcomingGamesList = snapshot.val()
    console.log('upcoming t2',upcomingGamesList)
    return upcomingGamesList
})
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my question, can you explain me how can I get the updatedList after all the changes?

Comment: in your answer you use once, I want to use ref('UpcomingGames') and once under ref('GameNotificationPrefences'). because If there is any change in ref('upcomingGames') I want to run the function again

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```js
export const deviceLogin = async (pin) => {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(`/devices/${pin}`);
    const snapshot = await ref.once('value');
    return snapshot.val();
}
```