# Using async await for firebase query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

At the moment I am performing a firebase query and logging the value, however I would like to manipulate my value outside of the function,which is tricky since firebase queries are asynchronous.
I want to do this since as code gets more complicated, it will get very messy having all my code nested within this query.

At the moment:
My database looks like this:

```
{
  "test" : "Hello from my database!"
}
```

my code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
database=firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('test');
var firebaseMsg ='';

 ref.on('value',function(snap){
   firebaseMsg=snap.val();
   console.log(firebaseMsg);
});
```

However, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
var firebaseMsg ='';
//attempting async/await
ref.on('value',async function(snap){
   firebaseMsg= await snap.val();

});    

//outside of the ref.on query
console.log(firebaseMsg);
```

So the console.log (or other code I choose to manipulate my firebaseMsg) is outside of my ref.on query.

Comment: the callback in `ref.on` is called asynchronously ... just because you await inside it does not make it run synchronously

Comment: @JaromandaX do you know how I could make ref.on run synchronously?

Comment: no, asynchrony can not be made synchronous - the point of asynchronous callbacks is that you don't know when the callback will be called because it depends on some external "event" - to make the code synchronous, you'd have to wait for that "event" or know when it will happen ... javascript doesn't work that way

Comment: Since `on()` starts a continuous listener, it doesn't return a promise, and thus it can't be used with `async`/`await`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495594/firebase-onvalue-with-await-does-not-work-as-expected/50495823#50495823

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reflect a change in the database in your application UI through the `on()` listener, you **must** do it from within the callback function.

If your problem is about writing some "clean" code (i.e. to avoid "having all my code nested within this query") you can very well use a function, like:

```
function sayHello(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
   //Update your UI as you wish with the value of msg
}

ref.on('value',function(snap) {
   firebaseMsg = snap.val();
   console.log(firebaseMsg);
   sayHello(firebaseMsg);
});
```

---

Note that if you only need to read from your database **once** (and not continuously listening to it) you could use the `once()` method, which returns a promise, and in this case you can use async/await. See the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once).